# Stop Inserting into Table when Duplicate Value Detected Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, tweepy

I able to get data from tweets and store them into MySQL table.
but the problem is sometimes a tweet has duplicate tweets with same value.
I want to know if it's possible to stop inserting into table when duplicate value detected using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from models import TrainingTweets, db
import mysql.connector
import json
import tweepy
from tweepy.api import API

#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api=None):
        self.api = api or API()
        self.n = 0
        self.m = 50

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        self.n = self.n+1
        if self.n <= self.m:
            tweet = all_data["text"]
            username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
            label = "1"
            ttweets = TrainingTweets(label_id=label, tweet_username=username, tweet=tweet)
            db.session.add(ttweets)
            checkedtweet = TrainingTweets.query.filter(ttweets.tweet).all()
            if not checkedtweet:
                db.session.commit()
                print((username, tweet))
                return True
            else:
                print("Duplicate entry detected!")
                return False
        else:
            print("Successfully stored ", self.m, " tweets into database")
            return False

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["health"], languages=["en"], follow="")
```

here's my model.py:

```
class TrainingTweets(db.Model):
    tweet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tweet_username = db.Column(db.String(50))
    tweet = db.Column(db.String(191))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(191), unique=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    label_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('label.label_id'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrainingTweets, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Call parent constructor.
        self.generate_slug()

    def generate_slug(self):
        self.slug = ''
        if self.tweet:
            self.slug = slugify(self.tweet)
```

Comment: Do you mean as in "stop the presses" and the whole listener stops, or just "ignore this IntegrityError"?

Comment: is it possible to skip inserting when there's duplicate and continue inserting a new one? this is what I want to do actually.. but if it's not possible to do that then I want to stop the whole listener if there's duplicate.

Comment: Have you set up a unique index on your table? IOW what's `TrainingTweets` like?

Comment: TrainingTweets has tweet_id, tweet_username, tweet, label_id, slug and created_date.
And yes I've set up a unique index on my table (tweet_id).
I also have set column tweet_username to be unique so if there's duplicate it won't insert the data.

Comment: Could you include the whole model class in your question (edit it there). You say you've set up the tweet_id as well, but you don't include it in your example code. Is that on purpose?

Comment: i've changed my question. :) you can check it above. and yeah it's on purpose because it's auto increment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model should have unique indexes for some criteria to remove duplicates on. `Column`s are not unique by default, which you seem to assume (`unique=False` in a column and the comments). You should either instead of an auto incrementing surrogate key use some "natural" key such as the id provided by twitter, or make the text column `tweet` unique.

When you've fixed the uniqueness requirements and if you wish to ignore `IntegrityError`s and keep going, wrap your inserts in transactions (or use the implicit behaviour) and commit or rollback accordingly:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet_id = all_data["id_str"]
        tweet_text = all_data["text"]
        tweet_username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        label = 1
        ttweets = TrainingTweets(label_id=label,
                                 tweet_username=tweet_username,
                                 tweet=tweet_text)

        try:
            db.session.add(ttweets)
            db.session.commit()
            print((username, tweet))
            # Increment the counter here, as we've truly successfully
            # stored a tweet.
            self.n += 1

        except IntegrityError:
            db.session.rollback()
            # Don't stop the stream, just ignore the duplicate.
            print("Duplicate entry detected!")    

        if self.n >= self.m:
            print("Successfully stored", self.m, "tweets into database")
            # Cross the... stop the stream.
            return False
        else:
            # Keep the stream going.
            return True
```

Comment: thanks! @Iija this is what I want. :) now it's working like charm! :D

Comment: Ah, well good that it's working. Your model was such that I wrote a foreword in the answer about uniqueness, but it seems you don't need it.

Comment: well I've noted what you describe above so thank you so much. :)